# Visual Studio 2017 - Git won't undo changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Working with Visual Studio 2017 and running into an odd problem.  When I make changes to a file and then try to undo them, by right clicking the file and selecting 'undo', the actual code shows as undone but the file is still marked as changed in the Changes panel/Solution explorer.  Fairly new to git so not sure where to even start.

Comment: Perhaps there are other changes not undone to that file?  Try viewing a diff of the file against the current repository version.

Comment: No, just changing one file and I'm only adding a comment.

Comment: Then maybe it's a bug...wouldn't be the first time I heard of a bug in an IDE's Git plugin.

Comment: If the file was not changed from the Git point of view and you changed it by using "undo", *then* it will be changed.

Comment: It may be that the file has some 'inconsequential" change, such as if VS changed line endings and didn't set them back when undoing.  You could use `git diff` to see what (if anything) git thinks has changed.  You could use `git checkout -- <path>` to have git restore the file to its previous state.  It's not *impossible* that it could be a bug, but it's extremely unlikely; usually when someone suggests that, it means they don't understand what's going on and have given up on trying to, but won't just say so.

Comment: ps - if it is something like line endings, then depending on your terminal the output from `git diff` may not be entirely clear either; but if `git diff` shows changes while `git diff -b` does not, that would mean whitespace has changed - spaces to/from tabs, line endings, something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I just had to reclone it from the server repo choosing "Clone in Visual Studio" and now the problem is gone.  Not sure why cloning from the command line would have caused that.